# MATLAB Plotting Inner Matrix elements must agree

Tags: matlab, plot

So I'm just trying to plot 4 different subplots with variations of the increments. So first would be `dx=5`, then `dx=1, dx=0.1 and dx=0.01 from 0<=x<=20`.

I tried to this:

```
%for dx = 5
x = 0:5:20;  
fx = 2*pi*x *sin(x^2)
plot(x,fx)
```

however I get the error `inner matrix elements must agree`. Then I tried to do this,

```
x = 0:5:20
fx = (2*pi).*x.*sin(x.^2)
plot(x,fx)
```

I get a figure, but I'm not entirely sure if this would be the same as what I am trying to do initially. Is this correct?

Comment: Please use the same editing process I used to your future questions. Your questions will be solved faster if they are readable.

Comment: Thank you so much! and I wasn't really sure how to format it that way, but I will be sure to do it next time.

Comment: @Tofurkey, I suggest you add that as an answer. IMO it's best when answered questions appear answered on the front page. I could have done it, but I don't want to steal your imaginary internet points. :P

Answer (score 0):

The initial error arose since two vectors with the same shape cannot be squared (`x^2`) nor multiplied (`x * sin(x^2)`). The addition of the `.` before the `*` and `^` operators is correct here since that will perform the operation on the individual elements of the vectors. So yes, this is correct.

Also, bit of a more advanced feature, you can use an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) to aid in the expressions:

```
fx = @(x) 2*pi.*x.*sin(x.^2); % function of x

x = 0:5:20;
plot(x,fx(x));
hold('on');

x = 0:1:20;
plot(x,fx(x));
hold('off');
```